# Certificate Pinning with PHP cURL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, game-center

I see there is tons of post in SO, about error:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

And which is the one I am getting.

All of their answer is just saying download root certificates from:

https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

And setting into the CURLOPT_CAINFO or setting php.ini's curl.cainfo.

But what this does is actually just telling cURL to trust the list of root CA and their trusted CA.

From my understanding, Certificate Pinning should ignore all these root CA and just trust the single certificate of a particular provider.

What is the correct way to fix this error?

```
    $ch =  curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/etc/httpd/static.gc.apple.com.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, '/etc/httpd/');

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY, "sha256//TeyzGG/8dvpuksAeSCb3tsvLEHbY6w9q63tXhOIf0Tg=");
    $sslCertificate = curl_exec($ch);
```

I know for libcurl itself, it has a option "CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY" which do absolutely what I need, but currently PHP still not supporting it... (it doesn't have such constant in PHP and I have no idea what is the actual value of the constant)

Comment: Could always try using the integer value of `CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY` as defined by the curl library, even if PHP does not provide an equivalent constant, check [the curl header](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h) for the values. Make sure that PHP is using a version of cURL which would support it.

Comment: To follow @apokryfos's point, the value of `CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY` is 230, hence try:

`curl_setopt($ch, 230, "sha256//TeyzGG/8dvpuksAeSCb3tsvLEHbY6w9q63tXhOIf0Tg=");`

Comment: @Carey From what I read in curl header that apokryfos posted, the value is 10230. since STRINGPOINT is 10000.  But either way, it doesn't worked out.  I don't see any changes after applying it, I can connect to any https server.  But I confirmed the cURL version is 7.49.1, which should be supported.  And using command curl: curl --pinnedpubkey "sha256//TeyzGG/8dvpuksAeSCb3tsvLEHbY6w9q63tXhOIf0Tg="  --url https://google.ca gave me proper error too.

Comment: Have you succeeded in solving this issue? I have the same problem and just can't seem to solve it... Thanks!

Comment: @hpuiu Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue is because the PHP itself installed with yum from Remi didn't compiled with the curl and openssl that support it.
So we have to update curl, openssl, compile PHP from source and it worked.

Comment: I have tried this even with the latest PHP ( 7.0.11 ) which has curl extension built with curl 7.50.1. The support for pinning the certificates is now build in, so the CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY is defined (10230) and so on, but even if I set certificate pinning, I still get same `Got error 60 - SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` error as witout pinning set. Shouldn't I get the specific `curl: (90) SSL: public key does not match pinned public key!` error if the fingerprint would be wrong?